# Wordpress website responsive won't show revolution slider on mobile version

Tags: wordpress, responsive-design, html5-video, revolution-slider

I just finished creating this website from a theme I purchased on ThemeForest. It said to be Full-responsive, but somehow it won't display the Slider and the video on mobile, as it does in the desktop version.
I've tried looking at the css file and try to figure what might cause this, but I don't have much experience with @media. The website's address is http://topnotchweddingvideos.com/. I've also went over the documentation for the Revolution Slider and couldn't figure it out. If someone could take a look at it and suggest what I could do would me much appreciated. I don't expect anyone to do the work for me, I'm just trying to get some feedback or ideas.

P.S. It would also be good enough if I could have the video only display before About Us in the mobile version.

Comment: "from a theme I purchased on ThemeForest": Why not ask theme support at ThemeForest? Why would anyone here be using your same theme and slider?

Comment: I know it's a long shot. I already emailed them but they take too long to respond and their answers are not very helpful.

Comment: The CSS selector `@media (max-width: 767px)
.widget_revslider {display" none;}` is the code that makes the revolution slider disappear. You could try changing the setting to `display" block;`, though more styling may be needed to get the results you need.

Comment: Thank you @Hubvill, got it working yesterday. I changed the .widget_revslider and it displayed on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Change The theme!!
or reach to developers of the theme. There's problem in theme. i also have used the revolution slider in my wordpress site working 100% in mobile. your Theme is not 100% responsive